# ¿Como busco registro de una relación en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo la tabla Solicitudes y la tabla estado estan relacionadas de uno a mucho. Un estado puede tener varias solicitudes.

Función del modelo Solicitudes

```
>   public function estado(){
>       return $this->belongsTo(Estado::class); //es estado de solicitud   }
```

Función del modelo estado

```
public function solicitudesDeServicio(){
    return $this->hasMany(SolicitudServicio::class);
  }
```

Generalmente en php uno arria un where con un joins para que traiga todas las solicitudes dependiendo del estado pero en este caso no se como se aria.

La tabla estado tiene atributos (id, name, description)

Ejemplo de la tabla estado

id:1
name:Pendiente
description: solicitud esta en espera de algo

**Es decir lo que quiero es digamos obtener una lista de solicitudes que tengan estado pendientes.** utilizando la relaciones entre los modelos

Comment: ¿cuál es tu problema exactamente? No me queda claro que es lo que quieres obtener como resultado.

Comment: @Shaz Pregunta actualizada Es decir lo que quiero es digamos obtener una lista de solicitudes que tengan estado pendientes. utilizando la relaciones entre los modelos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `whereHas`, él cual permite hacer consultas en la relación con un callback, y voy a asumir que el nombre del estado es "pendiente":

```
$solicitudesPend = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'pendiente');
})->get();
```

Más información, en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getListSolicitudes(Int $limit = 20)
    {



        $model = $this->model->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        $model = $model->with($this->includes)
            ->where(function ($query)
            {
                $query->where('name', 'pendiente');
            });

        if (empty($limit)) {
            return $model->get();
        }

        return $model->paginate($limit);

    }
```

Yo usaría algo así donde la variable `$this->model` es tu modelo y `$this->include` es la relacion entre modelos y su numero de paginacion